# Ember markup breaks bootstrap CSS

Tags: ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am generating a button group with a template:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    {{#if allowNew}}
        {{#link-to newRoute type="button" class="btn btn-primary"}}<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{t generic.add}} {{capitalize singularHuman}}{{/link-to}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if allowDeleteAll}}
        <button type="button" {{action "destroyAllRecords"}} class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i> {{t generic.delete_all}} {{capitalize pluralHuman}}</button>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Ember is placing `<script>` nodes inside the button group, I imagine to handle binding, view updates or whatever.

The problem is that bootstrap is relying on CSS rules like

```
.btn-group>.btn:first-child:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle)
```

to finetune the styles. Since the `<script>` tag is placed before the first `<button>` or `<a>` tag, and after the last one, those CSS rules are getting applied where they should not, and instead of having something like this:

[image: Rounded buttons]

I get something like this:

[image: Not rounded buttons]

As you can see the stock bootstrap style has rounded corners for the first and last button (the external corners), but my implementation has no such rounded corners.

Is it possible to somehow overcome this problem?

Comment: I don't mean to sound snarky, but you could write a little extra CSS to round the corners? Until Ember implements HTMLBars, those script tags are going to be everywhere. :(

Comment: Sure I could, but I would like to avoid it if there is a better solution. Which I can not think of. That's why I ask.

Comment: BTW: what is HTMLBars? [this](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars)?

Comment: Exactly. Ember is going to be implementing that. See this slideshow: http://talks.erikbryn.com/htmlbars-emberconf/#/16

Comment: That looks very cool! I hate those script tags: they make the markup difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ember view. See https://coderwall.com/p/f1npbg

```
App.MyView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  classNames: ['btn-group'],
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{view.content.name}}"),
    tagName: 'button',
    classNames: ['btn']
  }),
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle'],
  'data-toggle': 'buttons-radio'

});
```